# Creating a new version an existing customml Model Via Rest /python?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have tried using the json format via rest api and Vertex AI python code as shown in the above image for training a new version of a model, it is giving me the error as in the screenshot error i mentioned.

I have checked the json format as well, and it is not a valid format given in the documentation. The veretx AI SDK is just listing the models custom ML Model.

Reference Link: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-custom-job#create_custom_job-drest
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubWCc.png).

Please help me in retraining the custom model via API/Veretx AI SDK